# Couple of nice to knows to implement for the employer side

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs

A lot of important factors aside from remote work and offers relocation are important to a lot of people when finding a job.  Feature request, give employers an option to enter the following information:

1. Potential to grow in the company. (advancement, is there any room for it)
2. Culture (especially on the management side)
3. Dress Code (some people would prefer to wear jeans rather than the buttoned up corporate environment)

These would play as awesome "advanced" filters on the candidate side.

Comment: @AHiggins - There are a lot of companies that will flat out tell you they are looking for position x with no desire to move up...and at the same time there is a lot of people who don't care to move up, they just want to do job Y till they retire.

Comment: Advancement opportunities: nope, optional, obligatory (up-or-out).  Advancement direction: along technical track, into management, both possible.  Though moving away from literal "advancement", maybe "mobility within company" is also interesting -- some people don't need a _promotion_ but don't want to do the same thing for many years either.

Comment: This is a horrible idea. Then you might as well have filters for everything.

Comment: @dan-klasson well, if they share a little more information so I can decide what I'm getting into... I'm all for it.

Comment: This is interesting. What sort of descriptions are you expecting for 2) `Culture (especially on the management side)`..?

Comment: Two out of those three are really vague...what filter options would you expect to see for "potential to grow in the company" and "management"? I could argue that my theoretical company changed tech stacks every year, and therefore you'd always be learning something new, which I call "potential to grow"...but that's entirely different from "career advancement" (in the traditional "I was a junior developer, then a senior developer, then a team lead" type of growing). Culture's even harder.

Comment: We definitely want to help get info that matters to you as early as possible, but there are some things that I really think you just can't know without talking to someone from the company.

Comment: Is this not too limiting for many situations? In some companies, employers may not be anticipating any advancement opportunities for a programmer but two years of growth later, there's a need for several more, and suddenly a senior role is created out of necessity where previously none existed. I understand the desire to have this but it seems too difficult to codify in a way that really works for everyone.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I think the idea behin JonH is just to automatize a few questions that come up in job interviews frequently anyway. For sure the answers are not written in stone and may change in the future. But since this is what one may ask anyway there might be some value in accelerating this part. For me this would be soft issues though. And I would not really trust that all companies are answering faithfully the career advancement question, while the culture question will likely result in a lot of indefinite babble and the dress code may be a rather less important issue.